# Debugging Bad Request 400 error

Tags: javascript, json, express, request, http-post

I'm trying to return a list of flights from Google's QPX Express API, howver I'm stumped on a bad request response:

```
{ StatusCodeError: 400 - {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"badRequest","message":"Invalid inputs: received empty request."}],"code":400,"message":"Invalid inputs: received empty request."}}
```

Is there something wrong with how I'm approaching the structure of the request? I'm using the `request-promise` library

```
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',

  qs: {
   "request": {
     "passengers": {
       "adultCount": 1 },
       "slice": [{"origin": "BOS",
                  "destination": "LAX",
                  "date": "2017-03-01"
                }]
              }
        },
    json: true
}

request(options)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue. The request needed to include the data in the `body` key with the content-type set to JSON.

This now returns data from the API as expected.

```
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  body: {
  "request": {
    "passengers": {
      "adultCount": "1"
    },
    "slice": [
      {
        "origin": "SFO",
        "destination": "LAX",
        "date": "2017-06-19"
      }
    ],
    "solutions": "1"
  }
},
  json: true
}

request(options)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.trips.tripOption[0].saleTotal)
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it:

```
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',

  qs: {
   "request": {
     "passengers": {
       "adultCount": 1 },
       "slice": [{"origin": "BOS",
                  "destination": "LAX",
                  "date": "2017-03-01"
                }]
              }
        },
    json: true
};

request(options)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

You forgot to end the uri string. Also please don't forget the semicolons.

Edit:
Try:

```
request({
    url: (your url here),
    method: "POST",
    json: requestData
},
```

where requestData will be your qs.

Comment: Apologies @MindRoller, I accidentally deleted the closing quote when I removed the api key to post this. It's still broken unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: Usually when you get 400 status code from API, that means that your request is not well formed. Please try sending this simple request first:
https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/v1/json.samples/SFOLAX.in.json

and see if you get the right answer. It's an example from Google API Guide. By the way: can't you send a simple AJAX request first? Instead of using promise API?

Comment: Yep I've looking into the formatting of the request and swapped it out with Google's example, still doesn't work unfortunately. I've debugged on Postman too and all the params are being sent across correctly. I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working. Is the API key in the right place? The reason why I'm using the request api is because I want to do this all on server side.

Comment: Try changing uri to url. See my updated answer. Another thing is: check your API key.

Comment: Unfortunately that's still returning the same error. I'm just working from Postman now to help debug. The request is going across but it's invalid. Still confused as to why it's not working.